# Adding the proxy in vite takes me to that proxy url on my localhost. I only want to use it for api calls to backend

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vite

Here is my vite.config.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { quasar, transformAssetUrls } from '@quasar/vite-plugin'

const path = require('path');

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    globals: true
  },
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        transformAssetUrls
      }
    }),
    quasar({
      sassVariables: 'src/assets/scss/quasar-variables.sass'
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    },
  },
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/socket': {
        target: 'wss://abc-website.com:4221/',
        changeOrigin: true,
        ws: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace('^/socket', ''),
      },
      '/streaming/': {
        target: 'https://abc-website.com/',
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
      '/': {
        target: 'https://abc-website.com/',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        ws: true
      },
    }
  }
})
```

whenever my application is loaded it takes me to the https://abc-website.com while being on my locahost port.

I want to use above url for backend api calls only like https://abc-webite.com/api/auth.

Also i set the baseURL to "api/" after setting the proxy in vite.config.ts.

Also after the slight change it calls the REST api like https://localhost:3000/auth, i should rather be https://locahost:3000/api/auth

Vite proxy doesn't seems to work properly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could something like this:

```
server: {
  proxy: {
    // ... your other proxies
    '/api': {
      target: 'https://abc-website.com/',
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: false,
      ws: true,
      rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/app/, ''),
    },
  }
}
```

Then all your requests to sites like `localhost:3000/api/my-endpoint` should be proxied to `https://abc-website.com/my-endpoint`. You cannot proxy all "basic" requests, 'cause they are reserved for serving everything else, all the assets, index.html's and etc., but I'm also kind